# How to launch firefox with chrome:// protocol schema

Tags: firefox

I have added a extension in firefox, and Now, I want to use command line to launch firefox with chrome protocol schema.

`firefox.exe chrome://xxx-extension/content/index.html?locale=default&id=1100`

but above parameter can not work. which can **work** with **chrome** browser (chrome.exe)

So, how can I launch firefox to open extension local page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, It does not work. What you need to pay attention is the "chrome://", it's a custom schema which is registered in the OS to tell the OS which app it should launch.

For example, you can [register your custom one in Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: if I open firefox, and put ```chrome://xxx-extension/content/index.html?locale=default&id=1100``` in tab url, firefox can open it.

Comment: The reason is when you pass the uri as a parameter in command line, the app will filter some custom schemas which the app can not take by itself. The firfox.exe just take urls as its parameter in "-url"(this option can be omitted).https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Comment: I find that it can support as ```firefox -chrome chrome://inspector/content``` in link. and I can open page now, but it seems the page opened in a strange layout. (firefox window has no title, menu)

Comment: That sounds great, I haven't heard this "-chrome" option.